# Django - pagination - know number of pages

Tags: django-views

In Django, I want to know how I can get the number of total pages there are with ListView pagination.
I need to know it in the view not in the template.

```
class MyList(ListView):
     model = MyModel
     template_name = "template.html"
     paginate_by = 5

    def how_many(self):
        how_many_pages = ???
        return how_many_pages
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to use this? If it is in `get_context_data`, then that is easier, otherwise you will calculate it a second time.

Comment: I was lost where to look for that data. get_context_data has it. Thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this *in* or *after* the `get_context_data` call, you can find the `Page` object in the context with the name `'page_obj'`, and the `Paginator` as `paginator`:

```
class MyList(ListView):
     model = MyModel
     template_name = "template.html"
     paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        paginator = context['paginator']
        num_pages = paginator.num_pages
        # …
        return context
```